# Questions on Scikit-Learn early stopping

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, mlp

I have some questions on [Scikit-Learn MLPRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor) when early stopping is enabled:

1. Is the validation data (see 'validation_fraction') randomly selected, at the front, or at the back of the test data supplied?
2. Is the validation data the same or different during successive iterations of the training?
3. Will the validation data automatically be included/refit during the final stage of the training?
4. When the validation score is not improving by at least tol for n_iter_no_change consecutive epochs, will the previous best regressor be returned, or will the fit() function simply return the last regressor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the validation data (see 'validation_fraction') randomly selected,
>   at the front, or at the back of the test data supplied?

`MLPRegressor` uses `train_test_split` internally to create the validation data. If `shuffle` argument to the `MLPRegressor` is set to false then the fraction is taken from the end of the test data. If the `shuffle` is set to true then the data is randomly selected.

> Is the validation data the same or different during successive
>   iterations of the training?

Validation data is same for all the iterations of training

> Will the validation data automatically be included/refit during the
>   final stage of the training?

Validation data will never be used for training the model. It is used only for scoring the model.

> When the validation score is not improving by at least tol for
>   n_iter_no_change consecutive epochs, will the previous best regressor
>   be returned, or will the fit() function simply return the last
>   regressor?

If the validation score is not improving, instead of continuing, the early stopping will stop training the model (avoid overfitting) and return the models best parameter ([link](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7813f7efb/sklearn/neural_network/multilayer_perceptron.py#L570))

Comment: ok...i see. Could you be more precise in your answer to the last question? Say the validation scores over the iterations are ... 0.21, 0.22, 0.20, 0.19, 0.18 towards the end, will it return the regressor when the validation score is 0.22, or the one when it is 0.18?

Comment: @ChongLipPhang MLPRegressor will return the best parameters. ie the parameters for validation accuracy (0.22). Check the link in the updated answer.